# get value based on index dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to select a value from dropdown based on index. It is a super easy question. cannot find the property:

I though doing something like:

```
dll.Items[index]
```

But still do not know how to get value for this index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dll.Items.FindByIndex(index);` or `dll.Items.FindByValue(val);` according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

This loops through all items of an ASP combobox:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)comboBox1.DataSource;

for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    string displayText = dt.Rows[i][comboBox1.DisplayMember].ToString();
    string valueItem = dt.Rows[i][comboBox1.ValueMember].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can be done like below

```
dll.Items[index].value
```

btw, FindByIndex, is like not available